# ASP.NET validation - how to use parameters with DataAnnotation error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm currently trying to do model validation using DataAnnotations and defining the error messages in a resources file, as seen below:

```
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SiteResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField")]
    public string NomeCient { get; set; }
```

This works perfectly fine. However, I'd like to use parameters in my error strings, like one would do with string.Format().
For instance, imagine I want to validate a phone number like such:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\+?[\s\d]*$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SiteResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidField")]
```

In this case I'd want InvalidField to be something along the lines of "The value {0} is invalid. Please insert a valid {1}." where {0} would correspond to the user input and {1} to the field's display name.
So far I could not find a way to do this. As is, if the resource string includes {0} it will by default pull it from the DisplayName. Is there any way of also passing the input values? If not, what would the recommended alternative be?

Comment: You'd need to do this with an ActionFilterAttribute, it's not available OOTB